# CAN bus by NUCLEO-L432K2 (STM32CubeMXL4) not seen by apps

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, can-bus

Using specification UM1884 for the STM32L4, I have (essentially) programmed the following in main():

```c
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */
#define NOJI_DEFAULT_ID 102

/* USER CODE END PTD */
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
uint8_t currentID = NOJI_DEFAULT_ID;
CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef txHeader;
CAN_RxHeaderTypeDef rxHeader;
uint8_t txData[8];
uint8_t rxData[8];
uint32_t txMailbox;
int dataCheck = 0;

void HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef *Nhcan)
{
    static uint32_t count = 0;
    count++;
    memset((void *) &rxHeader, 0, sizeof(CAN_RxHeaderTypeDef));
    memset((void *) rxData, 0, 8);
    HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(Nhcan, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &rxHeader, rxData);
    if (rxHeader.DLC == 2)
    {
        dataCheck = 1;
    }
}
/* USER CODE END 0 */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_OK;
  CAN_FilterTypeDef canFilter;
  memset((void *) &canFilter, 0, sizeof(CAN_FilterTypeDef));
  canFilter.FilterActivation = CAN_FILTER_ENABLE;
  canFilter.FilterBank = 10;
  canFilter.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO0;
  canFilter.FilterIdHigh = currentID << 5;
  canFilter.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0xFFE0;
  canFilter.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
  canFilter.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
  canFilter.SlaveStartFilterBank = 18;
  status = HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1, &canFilter);
  status |= HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1);
  status |= HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan1, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING);
  memset((void *) &txHeader, 0, sizeof(CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef));
  txHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
  txHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
  txHeader.StdId = currentID;   // 0x66
  txHeader.DLC = 2;
  txHeader.TransmitGlobalTime = DISABLE;
  memset((void *) txData, 0, 8);
  txData[0] = 0xD7;
  txData[1] = 0xC3;
  status |= HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan1, &txHeader, txData, &txMailbox);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */
```

and my device is not seen on the CAN bus, using DroneCAN, MissionPlanner, or any other app. What am I missing, to get my device advertised on the CAN bus? My ISR is never hit.

Comment: When developing CAN drivers never touch filter and acceptance mask settings until you have everything else up and running.

Comment: You not seen message on the bus or message you send not detected by other devices? There are 2 different case which come from different root cause

Comment: I can see my own messages on the bus. The problem is no other device can see my device.